# Can anyone count my Schengen visa for me? Calculator seems to be broken

Tags: schengen-visas

I'm trying to visit Italy again so I can see one of my family members and I don't quite get the rule.

I know it's concept is about the first day you enter the Schengen zone, the 180 day count starts and you can't be in the Schengen zone over 90 days.

I'm not even sure if I violated the rule right now.

So my situation: I was in Italy on August 4-September 4 2018 and on January 11-March 7 2019. For 89 days total if my count was right...

So question #1: Did I violate the rule?
question #2: If I didn't violate it, when can I go back to Italy for 90 days fully?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the calculation in my answer below show, the OP can start a 90 day visit today, less than 90 days after the last visit (because that was not a 90 days continuous visit)

Comment: It's much easier if you count in reverse. On any day you are in the Schengen Area, you need to have been less than 90 days out of the previous 180 (including the current day for both). Given your dates, you can enter the Schengen Area now and stay for the full 90 days.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually, a 90-day visit must begin no sooner than the 91st day after the previous visit, because there must be 90 entire days of absence from the Schengen area. But a shorter visit can begin sooner than the 91st day after departure if the previous visit wasn't 90 days long.

Comment: @Henrik March 7 was more than 90 days ago.  For example, a 90-day Schengen visit starting on March 8 would end on June 5.  If I'm not mistaken, a 90-day visit would have been possible from June 6th or later, but only shorter visits would have been possible before.

Comment: I suspect that the calculator didn't work for you because you didn't enter the dates correctly.  They must be in day/month/year order, which is the order most commonly used in the EU, so `04/08/18`, `04/09/18`, `11/01/19`, and `07/03/19`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 August to 4 September is 28+4=32 days.
11 January to 7 March is 21+28+7=56 days.
Total 88 days.

As 4 September 2018 is more than 180 days ago, that trip is no longer relevant.

Until 10 June, 11 January is less than 180 days ago, so the entire trip counts, but you can't spend 34 (90-56) days in Schengen before 10 June, so it's mostly irrelevant.

On 3 September 2019, 7 March 2019 will be 180 days ago, so after that the second trip doesn't matter either.

If you enter Schengen now (1 July), it will be the 57th day within the last 180 days, tomorrow will then be the 58th, and so on until the 9th (tuesday next week) which will be your 65th day within the last 180. But on the 10th, January 11 suddenly falls out of the 180 day window, so the 10th will also be your 65th day within 180 days. And until 2 September, every day will then be the 65th, after that the count starts increasing again, so 3 September will be the 66th, and so on. Until 27 September which will be the 90th day within the last 180 days.

As a stay from now until 27 September only comes to 89 days in my count, I must have made a minor mistake in the calculation. But the conclusion is clear, you can stay 90 days from today, as your previous stay will move out of the 180 day window during the stay.

Comment: The second trip already doesn't matter. After 90 contiguous days outside Schengen everything that goes before is in practice irrelevant for the 90-in-180 rule.

Comment: The mistake in your calculation seems to be that *4* September is the date on which the cumulative presence begins to increase, because 3 September is the first day on which the presence of 7 March no longer counts, so 4 September is the first day on which the impact of the January-to-March visit is the same as it was the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

Using the calculator gives me 88 days for your previous stays, no violation. You can enter for up to 90 days from today. Inputting a hypothetical entry date of 1st July gives a response of:

- start of 90 days period: 03/04/19
- start of 180 days period: 03/01/19
  The stay may be authorised for up to: 90 day(s)
  https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en

Comment: Even though the conclusion here is right, the answer might give the wrong impression that one can in general pick only a single 180-day period to consider.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the bullet points seem to be taken from the calculator itself, which will have been filled out for a hypothetical entry on 1 July (today).  The calculator implicitly takes into account the ninety 180-day periods that end on each of the next 90 days when it says "The stay may be authorised for up to: 90 day(s)"